# How to show a bunch of figures in two columns?

Tags: floats, two-column

I have a bunch of figures of type-1 and type-2. How can I show these in two columns such that type-1 is displayed in the left column and type-2 in the right column?

Comment: Putting them into a `\begin{tabular}{cc}`?

Comment: Worked, thanks!

Comment: Depending on the expected output and alignment, you don't need a `tabular` environment. The following should also work: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
\end{document}`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
\hbox to\hsize{%
   \vtop{\kern0pt figures of type-1}\hss 
   \vtop{\kern0pt figures of type-2}%
}
```

Of course, all figures have to be inserted in vertical mode and their maximal width must be less than the column width. If you plan to insert a text in paragraphs into the column, you must set `\hsize` to the column size inside the `\vtop`.

LaTeX's macro `\includegraphics` uses `\leavevmode`. it means that it leaves the vertical mode which is a little complication. You must put such `\includegraphics` to individual `\hbox`es in order to suppress the `\leavevmode` inside the macro.

Comment: The simplicity of such a thing compared to the Latex solutions is impressive, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image}\hfil
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par
    \caption{caption here}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-b}\hfil
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{caption here}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}}
```

Comment: yes, except `figure*` does not support `h` so `[h]` just disables `p` and `t` so forcing the figure to the end of the document.  so you should drop `[h]` (also you don't need the mwe package to use example-image)